# DocumentFile как понять он локальный или сетевой?

Tags: android, файловая-система, contentprovider

Есть такой класс [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html) - введен начиная с API=22

Можно ли как то понять, что этот `DocumentFile` указывает на файл в локальной файловой системе или указывает на абстрактный документ в облаке?

Буду благодарен за любые ссылки, подсказки.

**P.S.** `DocumentFile.isVirtual()` - это про другое

Comment: Может это? `boolean isDocumentUri (Context context, Uri uri)`

Comment: Нет, это показывает кто дал ссылку на документ - провайдер или файл. К несчастью или к счастью - класс `com.android.externalstorageprovider` дает ссылку на документы на карте памяти и он же дает ссылку на `DocumentFile` - так что однозначного ответа `isDocumentUri()` не дает